# Show that $M+(r)$ is an ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is the question from abstract algebra.

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with 1, and $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.
Take $\bar{r} \in R/M$, $r$ is not contained in $M$.

Show that $M+(r)=M+rR$ is an ideal of $R$.

Showing the additive subgroup is easy.

And, take any $a \in R$, then $a(M+rR)=aM+arR \subset M+rR$.(*)

In (*), $aM \subset M$ is obvious. But how can I complete that...?

Comment: Is the exercise really to show that $M + (r)$ is an ideal, or that $M + (r) = R$? If the aim is really to show that $M + (r)$ is an ideal, you can show more generally that the sum of any two ideals is an ideal.

Comment: You can complete it by $a\cdot (r)\subset (r)$. This is the same argument as $aM\subset M$.

Comment: That $\;M\;$ is a *maximal* ideal is irrelevant here. The exercise remains exactly the same if $\;M\;$ is **any** ideal. Perhaps, as Marktmeister commented, you must show that in fact, in this case, $\;M+(r)=R\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

To finish the proof, we want to show $a(M + (r)) \subseteq M + (r)$.

Let $m + xr \in M + (r)$. Then $a(m+xr) = am + axr$. But $am \in M$ since $M$ is an ideal, and $axr \in (r)$. So $am + axr \in M + (r)$, as needed.

As is pointed out in the comments, we never used maximality of $M$, principality of $(r)$, or $r \not \in M$. The same proof shows that for any ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$, the set $I + J$ is again an ideal. In fact, it is the smallest ideal containing both $I$ and $J$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^